# Compiz>ubuntu unity plugin> workspace switcher

Tags: unity, gui, workspaces

I'm using desktop switcher from the ubuntu unity plugin and easystroke to get the macbook pro feel with switching workspaces. Everytime I use it to switch right or left a little animation like thing pops up as I'm switching (pic below). Is there a way to remove the circled animation from popping up every time I use the switcher? I can ignore it, but it would be nice to hide it some way. I'm not very savvy with linux, but I will try to follow along as best I can. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to install [compizconfig-settings-manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager], then run `ccsm` and disable the option to show a preview in the Desktop wall plugin:

[image: wall plugin]

Comment: sweet, thanks. I thought there was a way with ccsm. Now it acts more like Mac.